# How to use class type parameter in static member?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement the following pattern. A class where subclasses should have static `defaults` property, an `options` constructor argument, and an `$options` instance property that holds the merged values of the former two values. All three should have the same shape. Something like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
  static defaults: T
  $options: T

  constructor (options: T) {
    this.$options = Object.assign({}, Foo.defaults, options)
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error for `static defaults: T`:

> Static members cannot reference class type parameters.

Then, TypeScript sets the type of `defaults` to `any`. After that, if I do this:

```
interface BarOptions {
  length: number
  color: string
}

class Bar extends Foo<BarOptions> {
  static defaults = {
    length: 'oops' // should be number
  }
}

let bar = new Bar({
  length: 42,
  color: 'green'
})
```

The object in `new Bar({...})` is correctly type-checked, but `defaults` isn't, as it's considered `any`. This means I can mistakenly set `length` to `string` without an error. How to avoid this?

I read about the difference between static and instance sides of classes [in the docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes), but I still don't know how to solve this problem. Is there a solution at all?

## Edit

It appears I can do it this way, although a bit clumsy:

```
class Foo<T> {
  static defaults: any
  $options: T

  constructor (options: T) {
    this.$options = Object.assign({}, Foo.defaults, options)
  }
}

interface BarOptions {
  length: number
  color: string
}

class Bar extends Foo<BarOptions> {
  static defaults: BarOptions = {
    length: 12,
    color: 'black'
  }
}

let bar = new Bar({
  length: 42,
  color: 'green'
})
```

Is there a better way that doesn't require explicitly setting `static defaults: BarOptions` in `Bar`?

Comment: The static member can only initialize once regardless of how many different instances there are of Foo<T> which is why you can't use a static member of type T because there could be many different types for T but only one static field. What you could do is create an array or lookup based on T and get your defaults that way.

Comment: T is "dynamic", so trying to define "static" to be "dynamic" doesn't make sense. Why do you need that property to be static?

Comment: I edited my question. @Igor could you explain what you're suggesting? I don't think I get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define `static` properties using dynamic `T` signature. What you could do is define `abstract class` and force any subclass to implement `getDefaults` method:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
  abstract getDefaults(): T
  $options: T

  constructor (options: T) {
    this.$options = Object.assign({}, this.getDefaults(), options)
  }
}

interface BarOptions {
  length: number
  color: string
}

class Bar extends Foo<BarOptions> {
  getDefaults(): BarOptions {
    return {
      length: 3,
      color: "red"
    };
  }
}

let bar = new Bar({
  length: 42,
  color: 'green'
})
```

Please see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wHgBUA+BAbwCgEFRIZ4EBzAUwgBEmAzYAV2QjAAUASgBcCApQQASbAAcIAS2wA7MGImTYK2t3jYoCAXMXb1QspKoQAFgrAA6GfKWqEAXgQB5EACsm8ezQwBQZlAVIAXwAaBBs7e2Y2Th4+QSEY4xcwIUkI8jzyBWUIJiguWCYEACFgKE9nbQsqZCZlBhsxZW4AWxBSzWxkfTFaIoZ88nIUIOrahCYADxLlABMMHHwauobVEgoqRPYuXn5hMS36k1d9qgQoFm4oZSbb5tb26zEAZijLW60hlAxAAie4rYF-CIAblyE3ILUQIDmHmUTAA7rMoOFJC02h0EAAWABMvyoAOGCAA5Ax7q1KfkhEA).

Comment: This can't work for me because I need `defaults` to be editable like this: `Bar.defaults.color = 'blue'`

Comment: Let's say you define `Bar.defaults.color = 'blue'` and then you initialize your `Bar` instance and then later on you say `Bar.defaults.color = 'red'`. What would you expect from your code - which part should break and alert for error?